# Setting FontFamily of Button to StaticResource from code

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Looking for the code-behind equivilant of `FontFamily={StaticResource FontAwesomeBrands}`.

I've tried setting it directly to that string and was not too suprised when that didn't work. If I use that FontFamily in the XAML it works fine, just not sure how to do this from the code-behind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call any resource from the Resources file just with the resource name.

```
        var OnPlatformDic = (OnPlatform<string>) App.Current.Resources["FontAwesomeBrands"];

        var fontFamily = OnPlatformDic.Platforms.FirstOrDefault((arg) => arg.Platform.FirstOrDefault() == Device.RuntimePlatform).Value;

        YourLabel.FontFamily = fontFamily.ToString();
```

Comment: I'm getting a `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'` when trying that.

It is finding the resource though, so that's something. The resource has Platform variants, gonna poke around there.

Comment: For reference, this is the definition of that resource:
```l
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
                x:Key="FontAwesomeBrands">
                <On Platform="Android" 
          Value="FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Regular" />
                <On Platform="iOS" 
          Value="FontAwesome5Brands-Regular" />
                <On Platform="UWP" 
          Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Font Awesome 5 Brands" />
            </OnPlatform>```

Comment: Sadly no dice, your updated answer is indeed setting it to the correct value of `FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Regular`, but the text on the buttons is still showing as text, rather than FontAwesome icons

Comment: Ah hah! Got there in the end! Your answer was indeed correct. In case anyone stumbles upon this, my mistake was still using the XAML style encoding for the font values (like `&#xf1e8;`) when I needed to use the proper unicode escape values (like `\uf1e8`)